# Uncheck an item and "Select All" option from CheckedListBox on Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have added a checkbox list with some names and a select all option. I am able to select all check boxes in checkbox list when I select (Select all) option.

Problem here is, I am not able to uncheck (Select All) option whenever I uncheck any of the options from check box list.

Below is the vb.net code attached for (Select All) functionality.

```
Private Sub ChkLB_dl_name_cb_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ChkLB_dl_name_cb.ItemCheck        
    If e.Index = 0 Then
        Dim newCheckedState As Integer = e.NewValue
        For i As Integer = 1 to ChkLB_dl_name_cb.Items.Count - 1
            Me.ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(i, newCheckedState)
        Next
    End If 
End Sub
```

Below is an image of the checkbox list on the windows form, for your reference.

[image].

Comment: _"whenever I uncheck any of the option from check box list, I'm not able to uncheck `Select All`"_ Show the code where you try to uncheck the first item.

Comment: so u cant uncheck select all if u uncheck any other option?

Comment: for example:- If I uncheck B1, It should uncheck (Select All) and (B1). Because as I am deselecting B1, (Select All) will not be applicable.

Comment: How can I use filter in this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general i would use a `Boolean` variable to avoid that this handler is called for every item that you change programmatically. This will also fix the problem that you cannot uncheck the first item:

```
Private updatingListProgramatically As Boolean = False

Private Sub ChkLB_dl_name_cb_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ChkLB_dl_name_cb.ItemCheck
    If updatingListProgramatically Then Return

    If e.Index = 0 Then
        updatingListProgramatically = True
        For i As Integer = 1 To ChkLB_dl_name_cb.Items.Count - 1
            Me.ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(i, e.NewValue)
        Next
    Else
        Dim checked As Boolean = e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked
        If Not checked Then
            updatingListProgramatically = True
            Me.ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
        End If
    End If

    updatingListProgramatically = False
End Sub
```

The `Else` block seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Schmelter, that worked for me. I was missing that else part.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an Else for the first 'If' condition and add a second 'If' statement to check if "Select All" Check box is Unchecked or not.

```
Private Sub ChkLB_dl_name_cb_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ChkLB_dl_name_cb.ItemCheck       
    If e.Index = 0 Then
        If ChkLB_dl_name_cb.GetItemCheckState(0) = CheckState.Unchecked Then
            Dim newCheckedState As Integer = e.NewValue
            For i As Integer = 1 To ChkLB_dl_name_cb.Items.Count - 1
                ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(i, newCheckedState)
            Next
        End If
    Else
        ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like following you should get the desired functionality:

```
Private Sub ChkLB_dl_name_cb_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ChkLB_dl_name_cb.ItemCheck
    If e.Index = 0 Then
        Dim newCheckedState As Integer = e.NewValue
        For i As Integer = 1 To ChkLB_dl_name_cb.Items.Count - 1
            Me.ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(i, newCheckedState)
        Next
    Else
        'Remove the event-handler to prevent the ItemCheck-method from being called again
        RemoveHandler ChkLB_dl_name_cb.ItemCheck, AddressOf ChkLB_dl_name_cb_ItemCheck

        'If the item is being checked and all items are checked
        '(except "Select All"), then check "Select All"
        If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked AndAlso
           ChkLB_dl_name_cb.CheckedItems.Count + 1 = ChkLB_dl_name_cb.Items.Count - 1 Then
            'Check "Select All"
            ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Checked)
        Else
            'Uncheck "Select All"
            ChkLB_dl_name_cb.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)
        End If

        'Re-Add the handler
        AddHandler ChkLB_dl_name_cb.ItemCheck, AddressOf ChkLB_dl_name_cb_ItemCheck
    End If
End Sub
```